# How to return ties from aggregation functions in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a homework question which requires me to return the name of the oldest child of a person, and in case of ties return all the ties.

The schema for the database is:

```
create table persons (
  fname     char(12),
  lname     char(12),
  bdate     date,
  bplace    char(20), 
  address   char(30),
  phone     char(12),
  primary key (fname, lname)
);
create table births (
  regno     int,
  fname     char(12),
  lname     char(12),
  regdate   date,
  regplace  char(20),
  gender    char(1),
  f_fname   char(12),
  f_lname   char(12),
  m_fname   char(12),
  m_lname   char(12),
  primary key (regno),
  foreign key (fname,lname) references persons,
  foreign key (f_fname,f_lname) references persons,
  foreign key (m_fname,m_lname) references persons
);
```

My current query is

```
SELECT fname, lname, min(bdate)
from (SELECT *
    from persons
    JOIN births using (fname, lname)
    WHERE f_fname='Michael' and f_lname='Fox');
```

Where Michael Fox is the person in question. The expected output is

```
Q4|MFOld
Q4|MFOld2
```

however I am only able to get the first oldest child. I tried using a `With` statement, but we are not allowed to use views or temporary tables to answer this question. I also looked into using Rank (), but to my knowledge, that was introduced insqlite v3.25, but this question will be tested using v3.11. Any insight as to how the ties can be returned?

Comment: Did you [already ask this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302021/how-to-select-the-oldest-date-with-ties) with a different account, or is that a classmate? You should compare notes if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RANK()`:

```
SELECT fname, lname, bdate
FROM (
    SELECT 
        b.fname, 
        b.lname,
        p.bdate, 
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY bdate) rnk
    from persons p
    JOIN births b using (fname, lname)
    WHERE b.f_fname='Michael' and b.f_lname='Fox'
) x
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

If you ever need to remove the where clause in order to get the oldest child(ren) for each person, then you would need to add a use a `PARTITION`:

```
SELECT fname, lname, bdate
FROM (
    SELECT 
        b.fname, 
        b.lname,
        p.bdate, 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY b.f_fname, b.f_lname ORDER BY bdate) rnk
    from persons p
    JOIN births b using (fname, lname)
) x
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

---

In SQLite < 3.25, where window functions such as `RANK()` are not available, you can use a common table expression (available since version 3.8) to pull out all children of Michael Fox and use `NOT EXISTS` to filter on the oldest one(s):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT b.fname, b.lname, p.bdate
    FROM persons p
    JOIN births b using (fname, lname)
    WHERE b.f_fname = 'Michael' AND b.f_lname = 'Fox'
)
SELECT *
FROM cte c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM cte c1 WHERE c1.bdate < c.bdate
)
```

Comment: Tried this verbatim, and sqlite returns saying "Error: near line 1: near "(": syntax error."

Comment: @cs_pool_besty: which version of sqlite are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.11

Comment: @cs_pool_besty: `RANK()` is available since version 3.25 only. I added a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: We are also not meant to use temporary tables to solve this problem though.

Comment: @cs_pool_besty: there is no temporary table involved in this query... Are you able to test it against your data, do you get the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need min, itll be same for all rows as theres no group by just replace it with normal date

```
   SELECT fname, lname, b_date, 
   row_number() over (partition by b_date 
    order by fname, lname) 
   from (SELECT *
  from persons
 JOIN births using (fname, lname)
 WHERE f_fname='Michael' and 
  f_lname='Fox');
```